# How to deal with nested input in GraphQL

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

When writing queries I can define a resolver on any field and that field’s value will be determined by its resolver, regardless of query depth.

However when writing a mutation I seem to only be able to define the resolvers at the root level. Adding a resolve method to fields in my args or input type does not seem to have any affect.

What’s the best way deal with nested input in mutations?

Answer (score 28):

What do you mean by nested input in your mutations? GraphQL input types does not have resolvers. With resolvers you are just determining how to fetch results. If you would like to have nested input, e.g. for example I would like to create user also with company. I will then define `CreateUserInput` `CreateCompanyInput` type for example like this in SDL

```
input CreateCompanyInput {
   name: String!
   type: CompanyEnum!
}

input CreateUserInput { 
  username: String!
  firstname: String!
  lastname: String!
  company: CreateCompanyInput!
}

type Mutation {
  createUser(input: CreateUserInput!): User
}
```

This way I am basically nesting arguments and can implement more complex mutations. In addition I can reuse the `CreateCompanyInput` for `createCompany` mutation if I need mutation even for that. I will then have the whole CreateUserInput even with `CreateCompanyInput` in the `createUser` resolver as input argument. I can apply transactions as I will create two new records etc. Not sure if it is what you mean by nested input if you mean something else. Just let me know :)

Comment: What fronted are you using to query these? What does the frontend query look like?

Comment: This is the example mutation for create user. GraphQL request can look like for example as follows: ` createUserMutation($input: CreateUserInput!) { createUser(input: $input) { id, firstname, lastname } }`. For this code you need to also pass corresponding variables.

Comment: what would a `.graphql` file look like with `mutation CreateUser { createUser(input: { ... }) }`?

Comment: I think he means how to do this in express-graphql